# Differentiating data before exponential smoothing?

Tags: time-series, exponential-smoothing, differencing

I know that to perform exponential smoothing you don't have to make your time
series stationary, but I seem to get better results when I do it.
Do you know anything about it?

Comment: That's a bit odd. Differentiating amplifies noise, so I would expect you to get better results if you smoothed the data before differentiating. Can you maybe edit your question to include more context about your problem, and add some data and some code so the context is clearer?

Comment: I suppose you meant taking first differences? I have added the [tag:differencing] tag.

Comment: What do you mean by "better results"?

Comment: yes I meant differentiating the data before fitting exp-smooth model. better results means better accuracy than what I get without differentiating. maybe its just my data but I wonder if someone has read something about it.